# validatorjs (TypeError: Validator is not a constructor)

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation

I would like to use something to validate my json data on node.js server and I want to install validatorjs. Howhever I have a strange error when I add example to my project.

```
import * as Validator from 'validatorjs';

let data = {
  name: 'John',
  email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
  age: 28
};

let rules = {
  name: 'required',
  email: 'required|email',
  age: 'min:18'
};

let validation = new Validator(data, rules);

validation.passes(); // true
validation.fails(); // false
```

Im getting error on the console:

```
var validation = new Validator(data, rules);
                 ^

TypeError: Validator is not a constructor
```

What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why, but looks like they export Validator as default. This worked for me:

```
import Validator from 'validatorjs';

let data = {
  name: 'John',
  email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
  age: 28
};

let rules = {
  name: 'required',
  email: 'required|email',
  age: 'min:18'
};

let validation = new Validator(data, rules);

validation.passes(); // true
validation.fails(); // false
```